# Which one will be more efficient for shadow effect behind toolbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, core-graphics

I am writing an app on iOS platform, I want a shadow effect behind my toolbar like this,

[image]

- Currently I am using UIImageView for a start up, However I would like to know which one would be better choice? Using UIImageView or drawing a rectangle with gradient in it?

Thanks for any inout!

Comment: Am I missing something or would the simplest solution not be to add a shadow to the view's layer?

Comment: @Paul.s What do you mean? if you want shadow effect you must add effect by possible options yeah? Or I am missing something about apple's secret shadow effect checkbox :)

Comment: Each view is backed by a `CALayer`. Layers have shadow properties. You get a layer by doing `myView.layer`

Comment: @Paul.s, Let me check thanks! have you used that way previously?

Comment: Yup I have check this [tutorial](http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths) for some cool uses.

Comment: Hmmm I doubt that it will work on iOS, the example is for MacOSX apps :)

Comment: Have you tried it? I've used it before I'm not one for name dropping my apps but have one in the store with this used to create circular shadow underneath icons

Comment: Also I just checked and that blog pos i linkedt is about optimising shadows in a. iPad app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there going to be animated content overlapping your shadow? Because unless there is, I doubt it makes enough of a difference to matter. In which case, go with UIImageView, because it's easiest.

If there is going to be animated content, I would suspect you'll be able to wring slightly better performance out of drawing it yourself, but you're going to have to do some Core Graphics optimization (cache the drawn gradient, cache the CGGradient for redraws, etc.).

Beware premature optimization. BEWARE!

Comment: Thanks Kenny! I have no plan to create animation in this app so I will go with UIImageView, but I will make sure I use core graphics otherwise.